# VBA- Como mandar email automáticos com pptx/pdf em anexo

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, email, debug

Estou com esse código para enviar email com um arquivo em PPTX ou PDF para uma lista de pessoas, e ele para dizendo que não encontrou o arquivo. Notem que referenciei parte do nome do arquivo com uma celula que contém uma variável para que ele consiga mandar outro email sozinho.

```
Sub MandaEmail()
    
    Dim EnviarPara As String
    Dim Mensagem As String
 
    For i = 1 To 10
        EnviarPara = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)
        If EnviarPara <> "" Then
            Mensagem = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3)
            Envia_Emails EnviarPara, Mensagem
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

```
Sub Envia_Emails(EnviarPara As String, Mensagem As String)
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object
 
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    For lin = 1 To 2
    With OutlookMail
        .to = EnviarPara
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Teste"
        .Body = Mensagem & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Atenciosamente" 
 >>     .Attachments.Add (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Certificado_" & Cells(lin, 2).Value & ".pptx")
        .Send
    End With
    
    Next
    
    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

o problema acontece no Attachments.Add
alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Eu testei seu código e ele funciona. O que pode estar acontecendo é que está tentando anexar um arquivo que não existe.

O que você pode fazer é adicionar um `if` para verificar se o arquivo existe antes de tentar montar o e-mail e exibir uma mensagem para o usuário caso o arquivo não seja encontrado.

Essa verificação pode ser feita usando a função `Dir`, como, por exemplo:

> ```
> Dim CaminhoArquivo As String
>
> CaminhoArquivo = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\nome_arquivo.pptx"
>     
> If Dir(CaminhoArquivo) = "" Then
>     MsgBox "O arquivo " & CaminhoArquivo & " não existe."
>     Exit Sub
> End If
> ```

> ```
> .Attachments.Add CaminhoArquivo
> ```

### Código atualizado:

```
Sub Envia_Emails(EnviarPara As String, Mensagem As String, CaminhoArquivo As String)
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object
    Dim CaminhoArquivo As String
        
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    For lin = 1 To 2
        CaminhoArquivo = (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Certificado_" & Cells(lin, 2).Value & ".pptx")
    
        If Dir(CaminhoArquivo) = "" Then
            MsgBox "O arquivo '" & CaminhoArquivo & "' não existe e o e-mail não será enviado.", vbCritical
        Else
             With OutlookMail
                .to = EnviarPara
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "Teste"
                .Body = Mensagem & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Atenciosamente"
                .Attachments.Add CaminhoArquivo
                .Send
            End With
            
            MsgBox "Email enviado com o arquivo '" & CaminhoArquivo & "' como anexo.", vbInformation
        End If
    Next
    
    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```